# Delphi Class Destructor

Tags: class, delphi, destructor

I don't understand how a class destructor works! I read grammar semantics and syntax for a class destructor, but I haven't found many complete code examples.

I tried to create a simple code (see below), and that code eventually displays **Start**, but it does not display **Finish**.

Can you help me find a way how to display **Finish** by changing the code below within *Project1.dpr* and *Unit1.pas*?

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  Unit1 in 'Unit1.pas';

begin
  Race:= TRace.Create;
  Race.Destroy;
  Readln
end.
```

```
unit Unit1;

interface

type
  TRace= class
    class constructor Start;
    class destructor Finish;
  end;

var
  Race: TRace;

implementation

class constructor TRace.Start;
begin
  Writeln('Start')
end;

class destructor TRace.Finish;
begin
 Writeln('Finish')
end;

end.
```

I use Delphi Sydney 10.4 Community Edition.
Thx

Comment: We tend never to call `Destroy` directly and instead use `Free`. It makes no difference here, but it does when your code is inside a destructor.

Comment: It will display finish as the application closes, but the console disappears at the same time as it is displayed.

Comment: @BrankoSretenovic Have you read the documentation yet?  [Class_Constructors](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Methods_(Delphi)#Class_Constructors) and [Class Destructors](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Methods_(Delphi)#Class_Destructors)

Comment: David, you are right! I have added `Readln` below `Writeln('Finish')` and it worked. It's because finalization comes the last :).

Comment: @DavidHeffernan  Free ist just Destroy with checking for nil, how would it make a difference if the code is inside a destructor? May even be helpful coming from Languages with Heavy GC.

Comment: @AndyTroschke Because inside a destructor the code could be running on a partially constructed class so the nil check is safe against that. Granted the nil check is not necessary in a classic local var create / destroy inside a try / finally pattern. Which is what we have here (albeit with a global var rather than local, and the try / finally omitted. But the standard practice is to always use Free so you don't need to think about anything.

Answer (score 3):

The class destructor will run when the class itself (not an instance of the class) is disposed of, not for any individual object.  The class constructor will run when the class itself is created.

What that means is that when the class is loaded (during the initialization of the executable or package that the class code is in) the class constructor is run, and when the class is unloaded (or disposed of) (during finalization) the class destructor is run.

The class is a `TClass`, whereas instances of that class are descendants of `TObject` (`TRace` in your example).  So if you create a `TRace` it **does not** call the class constructor for TRace, similarly if you dispose of a `TRace` it **does not** call the class destructor for `TRace`.

The documentation which @RemyLebeau linked to in his comments makes it clear that these methods are '*not available to developers*' - you don't ever call them, the system does.

To get what you want you just need an ordinary instance destructor as shown:

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}
type
  TRace= class(TObject)
  public
    constructor Create;    // by convention we use Create
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;

constructor TRace.Create;
begin
  Writeln('Start');
  inherited Create();
end;

destructor TRace.Destroy;
begin
  Writeln('Finish');
  inherited;
end;

var
  Race: TRace;

begin
  Race:= TRace.Create;
  Race.Free;
  Readln;
end.
```

Using a `class constructor` and / or a `class destructor` is an unusual requirement.  It could be used to initialise static resources that are needed for the class to operate, but from code that I have seen it is more usual for this to be done in the `initialization` and `finalization` sections.

In Delphi `class` methods are called with `Self` referring to the class (a TClass) and not to an instance of the class and so they cannot access any instance data, but can still access any static data.

Comment: You never ever write a destructor that isn't overriding the virtual destructor declared in TObject

Comment: Yes, good spot.  I was in a hurry to post!

Comment: Class constructors / destructors have the benefit of allowing encapsulation. For instance if the static resources are strict private. And of course they are called from unit init/finit methods. I presume the docs say that.

Answer (score 0):

David's comment is correct. I have added `Readln` below `Writeln('Finish')` and it worked.

It's because finalization is the place where class destructor places its commands in, and finalization comes very last.

Comment: great to see you exploring Delphi.  The documentation clearly states that developers do not have access to class constructors and destructors so you don't call them - it seems that for what you want (to display messages when creating or disposing of an object) a standard constructor and destructor for objects of that class (instances).  The class is not an instance of itself, it's a TClass